# How to install older AGP version?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to install an older AGP verison so I can build my app on Java 11 in Android studio.

I tried changing the version of the project in build.graddle.kts to
`plugins { id("com.android.application") version "3.3.0" apply false }`
But it cant find that version to download - the oldest that I could use is 4.2.0, which gives out the error

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.7.1. Current version is 5.0.
> (I had to use gradle version 5.0. because of Java 11)

Any idea how I can downgrade my project to Java 11, gradle 5 and AGP version 3.3.0 ? or maybe just create a project from the start with that in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work as I haven't tried it, but feel free to give it a try.
1.Download the AGP 3.3.0 from their [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle).

2.Create a folder in your project (maybe `jars`), and put the downloaded jar file in that folder

3.Update you `build.gradle` file at project level to include this jar

```
    repositories {
     flatDir {
        dirs 'jars'
     }
    }
   dependencies {
    classpath name: 'gradle-3.3.0-all'
   }
```

4.Sync

Comment: It´s searching in the right directionary now, but not finding the file:
` Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '3.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
...
flatDir(...\MyApplication\jars)
...`

Comment: @giraffephant Can you share the gradle file code snippet?

Comment: `pluginManagement {
    repositories {

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        flatDir {
            dirs ("jars")
        }
    }
}


rootProject.name = "My Application"
include(":app")
`
is the setting.gradle.kts file, where I put it in, atleast it searched in the dir then ^^' if thats what you meant .